# Stop user interaction of outside the opened container

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a setting container (`filter-container`) which opens from a button click. I want it to open and the page should only allow interaction with that `filter-container`. So the `main-container` should not be scrollable and the visible `button` of it, should not be click-able until the `filter-container` is closed. This similar system can be found on `Instagram` on the desktop-version when opening a post and the outside page behind the post is not interactable. I cannot think of ways to create this system so need help. Also, I would very much appreciate if I can get a solution without the `CSS` interaction.

```js
let e = document.querySelector("filter-container"),
    b1 = document.querySelector("main-container button"),
    b2 = e.querySelector("button");

b1.onclick = function() {
    console.log("CLICK-ABLE");
    e.style.display = "block";
};
b2.onclick = function() {
    console.clear();
    e.style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
} main-container {
    display: block;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: rgb(110, 170, 250);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    z-index: 0;
} filter-container {
    display: none;
    height: 75%;
    width: 85%;
    background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 12.5%;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 1;
} filter-container button {
    margin-bottom: 2500px;
} button {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <main-container>
        <button>OPEN-FILTER</button>
    </main-container>
    <filter-container>
        <button>CLOSE-FILTER</button>
        <p></p>
    </filter-container>
</body>
</html>
```